# Downloading file from external sources using Salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, salesforce1-app

So I have my  LWC component which is trying to download files from external source using native js fetch api. There is no problem downloading small files using my code. But I'm having troubles downloading files that are > 750mb for single files and for zip(multiple) files, I can download up to < 2Gb afterwhich it breaks (0 bytes file downloaded or no response for long time). I'm not sure if its a LWC limitation as there are many components running or is it limitation of the javascript in salesforce? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this.

Here is the code logic

```
async getBase64Image(response) {
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = resolve;
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
  return reader.result;
}

async download(downloadUrl, zipped = false) {
  let response  = await fetch(downloadUrl {
                          method: 'GET'
                        ); 
                            
  let contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
  let element = document.createElement('a');
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  if (zipped) {
    contentType = "application/zip";
    let arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

    let blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: contentType });
    let content = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        
    if (content) {
      element.href = content;
      element.setAttribute('download', 'Zip');
      element.click();
    }
  } else {
    let base64Url = await this.getBase64Image(response);

    element.href = base64Url;
    element.setAttribute('download', this.fileNames[0]);
    element.click();
        
  }
}
```

Would like to know if there is a better practice for downloading file using LWC or there are some limitations that I'm not aware of?